# gradle can not find cacerts file: wrong direcrory looked up

Tags: java, cordova, ssl, gradle

I am trying to build cordova's android application with gradle. This command is executed by `cordova emulate android`:

```
platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=x86 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
```

This is complete output of that command:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.48.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:17.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:common:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:24.0.0
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:24.0.0
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:1.0.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:4.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:4.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.2.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:4.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:24.0.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:24.0.0
      > Failure initializing default system SSL context

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:180)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:444)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:205)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:142)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:131)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.1.
Required by:
    :android:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainAdapter.resolve(RepositoryChainAdapter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:577)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:587)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:272)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:246)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:156)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveDependencyGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:442)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Failure initializing default system SSL context
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:368)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:204)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:286)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:851)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.getResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveMetaDataArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:162)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:391)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$2.run(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:237)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:308)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:284)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyResolver.java:70)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/security/cacerts (Нет такого файла или каталога)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:279)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:366)
    ... 116 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.778 secs
```

Origin of error is:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/security/cacerts (Нет такого файла или каталога)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:279)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:366)
    ... 116 more
```

Actually, wrong directory scanned for `cacerts` file, it should be

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/**jre**/lib/security/cacerts

Why wrong directory scanned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/security
```

Comment: On my mac that helped: `sudo ln -sf $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security/cacerts $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/lib/security`

Answer (score -1):

For new openjdk installations you could also run just run :

```
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

known to work on